# Model with ForeignKey "missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I literally started with pythond and django a week ago. Watched a good bunch of tutorials and looked around here.

This is my model. Two tables, one with Customers and one with Applications. The applications are mapped to Customers.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer


class Application(models.Model):
    application = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey('Customer',on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.application
```

This is my view function to create a new customer

```
def new_customer_view(request, customer_id):
  form = CustomerForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    form = CustomerForm()

  context = {
    'customer': Customer.objects.get()
  }
  return render(request, 'forcast/new_customer.html', context )
```

When I try to access the form I get:

```
TypeError: new_customer_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'customer_id'
```

Comment: The error is likely in the URLs, did you add the `customer_id` parameter in the URL?

Comment: ARGH! You are right.